# MYSQL: how to find entries corresponding to MIN() of costly function

Tags: mysql, subquery, reusability, min

I am running a complicated and costly query to find the MIN() values of a function grouped by another attribute. But I don't just need the value, I need the entry that produces it + the value.

My current pseudoquery goes something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(COSTLY_FUNCTION(a.att1,a.att2,$v1,$v2)) FROM (prefiltering) as a GROUP BY a.group_att;
```

but I want `a.*` and `MIN(COSTLY_FUNCTION(a.att1,a.att2,$v1,$v2))` as my result.

The only way I can think of is using this ugly beast:

```
SELECT a1.*, COSTLY_FUNCTION(a1.att1,a1.att2,$v1,$v2)
FROM (prefiltering) as a1 
WHERE COSTLY_FUNCTION(a1.att1,a1.att2,$v1,$v2) = 
  (SELECT MIN(COSTLY_FUNCTION(a.att1,a.att2,$v1,$v2)) FROM (prefiltering) as a GROUP BY a.group_att)
```

But now I am executing the prefiltering_query 2 times and have to run the costly function twice. This is ridiculous and I hope that I am doing something seriously wrong here.

**Possible solution?:**

Just now I realize that I could create a temporary table containing:

```
(SELECT a1.*, COSTLY_FUNCTION(a1.att1,a1.att2,$v1,$v2) as complex FROM (prefiltering) as a1)
```

and then run the MIN() as subquery and compare it at greatly reduced cost. Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with your temporary table solution is that I can't see any way to avoid [using it twice in the same query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/temporary-table-problems.html).

However, if you're willing to use an actual permanent table (perhaps with [`ENGINE = MEMORY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html)), it should work.
You can also move the subquery into the `FROM` clause, where it might be more efficient:

```
CREATE TABLE temptable ENGINE = MEMORY
  SELECT a1.*,
    COSTLY_FUNCTION(a1.att1,a1.att2,$v1,$v2) AS complex
  FROM prefiltering AS a1;

CREATE INDEX group_att_complex USING BTREE
  ON temptable (group_att, complex);

SELECT a2.*
FROM temptable AS a2
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT group_att, MIN(complex) AS complex
    FROM temptable GROUP BY group_att
  ) AS a3;

DROP TABLE temptable;
```

(You can try it without the index too, but I suspect it'll be faster with it.)

**Edit:** Of course, if one temporary table won't do, you could always use two:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1
  SELECT *, COSTLY_FUNCTION(att1,att2,$v1,$v2) AS complex
  FROM prefiltering;

CREATE INDEX group_att_complex ON temp1 (group_att, complex);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2
  SELECT group_att, MIN(complex) AS complex
  FROM temp1 GROUP BY group_att;

SELECT temp1.* FROM temp1 NATURAL JOIN temp2;
```

(Again, you may want to try it with or without the index; when I ran `EXPLAIN` on it, MySQL didn't seem to want to use the index for the final query at all, although that might be just because my test data set was so small.  Anyway, [here's a link to SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/048yJkHZcI) if you want to play with it; I used `CONCAT()` to stand in for your expensive function.)

Comment: Thanks! Will that work with multiple users simultaniously or could they be using the same table by accident? If the solution from chris works, couldn't I avoid referencing the temorary table twice in a similar manner - by using HAVING?

Comment: Yes, two simultaneous users could end up trying to use the same permanent table; you could try to make that less likely by appending something unique (like [`CONNECTION_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)) to the table name.  That said, I just added a solution that does use temporary tables, so you may want to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HAVING clause to get columns in addition to that MIN value. For example:

```
SELECT a.*, COSTLY_FUNCTION(a.att1,a.att2,$v1,$v2) FROM (prefiltering) as a GROUP BY a.group_att HAVING MIN(COSTLY_FUNCTION(a.att1,a.att2,$v1,$v2)) = COSTLY_FUNCTION(a.att1,a.att2,$v1,$v2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is that less costly than using a temporary table? It still contains the function a few times. Or does mysql internally reuse the results?